# Post picture on my wall, the name, tile, description can display, but picture didn't. why?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

```
String url = "http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/2/Open/Golf%20Channel/Big%20Break%20Ireland/Showcard/_derived_jpg_q90_250x250_m0/SC_BBIreland.jpg?partner=pumaDemoTune2";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));
params.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
params.putString("picture", url);
params.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_action));
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new listener(), null);
```

the caption, name, description field can be displayed, but the picture didn't, does anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems you have a typo in your code there. Did you copy and paste it directly from your IDE?

```
String url = "http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/2/Open/Golf%20Channel/Big%20Break%20Ireland/Showcard/_derived_jpg_q90_250x250_m0/SC_BBIreland.jpg?partner=pumaDemoTune2"`
```

that should end with a ; and not with `

```
String url = "http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/2/Open/Golf%20Channel/Big%20Break%20Ireland/Showcard/_derived_jpg_q90_250x250_m0/SC_BBIreland.jpg?partner=pumaDemoTune2";
```

Comment: sorry, i type the wrong character in the question edit. but the  code in the eclipse is right.

Comment: @facebook-bszbrf Take a look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688957/android-how-to-post-picture-to-friends-wall-with-facebook-android-sdk/6707583#6707583)

Comment: @CharleyP. thanks for your reply, i use the feed, not upload the photos.

Comment: @facebook-bszbrf sorry about that. Hope [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728251/posting-to-facebook-feed-from-android-app) will help

Comment: @CharleyP. it return same result as my codes, the picture doesn't display, when i change the "picture" field to "link", the picture can display, or i use another url, such as "http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png", the picture also can display, do you know why?

Comment: @facebook-bszbrf If you change "picture" to "link" it works with your current url?

Comment: @facebook-bszbrf I honestly don't know why... but if it works, then I guess your problem is solved :)

Comment: @CharleyP. although use the "link" the picture can display, but i want to use the "link" field to do other works, for example, link to my website, so i still want to use the "picture" field to do this work. :(

Comment: @facebook-bszbrf Ok, try and use "picture" again with your current url but remove the query string "?partner=pumaDemoTune2" ... if that doesn't work try to put that same image in this location "http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/SC_BBIreland.jpg"

Comment: @CharleyP.  remove the query string doesn't work, and i don't have permission to change the picture's location, :(

Comment: @facebook-bszbrf Try using "http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/2/Open/Golf Channel/Big Break Ireland/Showcard/_derived_jpg_q90_250x250_m0/SC_BBIreland.jpg?partner=pumaDemoTune2" (replacing encoded spaces)... if that doesn't work then try with http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/pagerror.gif

Comment: @CharleyP.  yes, i use the blank space instead of the %20

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is having the same issue. The "picture" url should not be encoded.

The url...

```
String url = "http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/2/Open/Golf%20Channel/Big%20Break%20Ireland/Showcard/_derived_jpg_q90_250x250_m0/SC_BBIreland.jpg?partner=pumaDemoTune2";
```

should be:

```
String url = "http://stg-cps-static.rovicorp.com/2/Open/Golf Channel/Big Break Ireland/Showcard/_derived_jpg_q90_250x250_m0/SC_BBIreland.jpg?partner=pumaDemoTune2";
```